# How can I make a bash command to check out the latest version of a git branch?

Tags: bash, git, unix

I'm building some aliases in my `~/.profile` for common command strings. One case is when I begin a new feature branch, I will checkout the current base which has a naming convention of `release/1.1.0`, then make my new `feature/feature-name` branch from there.

My question is how to make my bash command automatically checkout the latest version. If I type manually and tab over the results, some of the projects have many available like `release/1.0.0`, `release/1.1.0`, `release/1.1.2`, `release/1.2.0`.

What can I add to my following function that can will default to the latest available version?

```sh
relb(){
  git checkout release/???
  git pull
}
```

Comment: not in the particular workflow my team is using for this project.

Comment: Ideally, whatever is *creating* the `release/whatever` branch should update a `release/latest` tag that coincides with whatever is, in fact, the latest version. Then you just checkout `release/latest` to get the latest version, whatever that happens to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--sort='-v:refname'` as an option to `git branch` to version sort by refname,<sup>1</sup> descending (the `-`); the `--format` option makes sure there is no unwanted whitespace in the output, and `head -n1` returns just one branch:

```
git checkout \
    "$(git branch \
        --list \
        --sort='-v:refname' \
        --format='%(refname:short)' \
        'release/*' \
    | head -n1)"
```

You might have to `git fetch` first.

Alternatively, you can do it without any external tools at all:<sup>1</sup>

```
git checkout \
    "$(git for-each-ref \
        --sort='-v:refname' --format='%(refname:short)' --count=1 \
        refs/heads/release/)"
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Hat tip to [Hauleth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017941/hauleth) for pointing out that `git branch` has sorting built-in and the `git for-each-ref` can do it all.</sup>

Comment: This is assuming the release branches are actually that, *branches*, and not tags. (And it really sounds like you should use tags instead of branches here.)

Comment: You do not need GNU sort as Git can handle it internally via `--sort=v:refname`.

Comment: It can be improved even further via `git for-each-ref --sort='-v:refname' --format='%(reframe:short)' --count=1 refs/heads/release` (replace `heads` for `tags` in case of tags).

Comment: @Hauleth I think I'll work under the assumption that everything can be done within Git directly from now on ;)